# janusgraph-full-1.0.0-rc1 for Production

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, janusgraph

I am planning to use following version of JanusGraph / Cassandra / ES for production environment. Just want to check if those are suitable for Production.

1. janusgraph-full-1.0.0-rc1
2. elasticsearch-7.17.5
3. apache-cassandra-4.0.7

I have create my docker files with appropriate config for these and am planning to setup them as dockers in production.

Please provide guidance on, if these are suitable for Production.

Thanks,
Atul

Answer (score 3):

The rc in janusgraph-full-1.0.0-rc1 stands for release candidate, so it is not the true release. You can find the last release, currently 1.0.0, at https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases. This page also lists the tested compatibility. More general, assumed/supported compatibility can be found at: https://docs.janusgraph.org/changelog/#version-compatibility-matrix